Can a particle have properties of both Dirac and Majorana particles?
Dirac fermions have antiparticles of opposite properties, and only a particle and an antiparticle can annihilate. Majorana fermions have no antiparticles because they can annihilate with themselves. Accordingly, only Dirac fermions can carry conserved charges like electric charges.
So what kind of fermions do neutrinos belong to? It’s of little doubt that neutrinos and antineutrinos are different particles because they are produced in opposite processes (beta decay or electron capture). They also carry opposite chirality. On the other hand, neutrinos don’t carry conserved charges which makes them a possible candidate of Majorana fermions. However, if a neutrino can annihilate with either an antineutrino or a neutrino, does that mean neutrinos and antineutrinos are actually the same? Does the Majorana equation allow the existence of antiparticles?

This is an open problem in neutrino physics. I believe some approaches even add both Dirac and Majorana masses to the same particle, but I'll let someone with a better knowledge about this discuss the details

I want answers from a theoretical standpoint. In another word, could it be possible to find a relativistic Schrodinger equation with combined features of Dirac and Majorana equation, which means it can predict particles and antiparticles with distinct properties, but can annihilate with each other or themselves.

A funny thing is that if proton decay is true, neutrons are also majorana fermions.
